# Silverlight Database connecting issue

Tags: database, silverlight

Hello guys I am working on silverlight and I have issue regarding on database connectivity.

I had tried with sqlce, but this is not working. I was tried with much of blog but still is not working.

so as well as MS Access also not connecting so is there any solution for the outofbroser application

I am really getting stuck. beacause I am using Isolation storage but it's still not providing ID so there is no scope to use it.

It's really solid problem I am suffering to using silverlight.

Is there any solution for this how to connect database with silverlight.

Thanks...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, always there is a solution.

Silverlight does not support Database connectivity, I know it seems weird but it is very good for a lot of reasons.

The solution is to **create a WCF Service and use it to get the data**.

`Silverlight <---> WCF Service <---> SQL Server`

Here is a simple example:
[Consuming WCF Services in Silverlight](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article279.aspx)

and here is an advanced one:
[Using WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/silverlight-4/using-wcf-ria-services/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to connect to a database directly from a Silverlight application.

That is not possible. Silverlight does not provide a way to connect to a database directly. You must use a Web Service instead.

Try looking into WCF Data Services/RIA Services. They work great with Silverlight applications.

Here is a [good tutorial from Brad Abrams](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2010/03/15/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-index.aspx) on RIA Services.