# get column names of a table from database in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq-to-entities, wcf-ria-services

how do i get column names of a table from database in domain service of the silverlight     application and then use these in the listbox  for  client to select . 
i looked through here  [LINQ Query to get Column Headers in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512132/linq-query-to-get-column-headers-in-silverlight) but 't was little  confusing .

As far as I know in Silverlight  u write domain service to reach the data in  the server side and silverlight creates the context in the client side and u use context there .So i assumed i need a  datacontext and i created one in the server side which reaches the same database and i  used that context in my method as the link above  but this time there was an exception like "System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code" and " Message=Keyword not supported: 'metadata'." i cant use  System.Data.Linq inn the client side so i can use that method in  the client side neither

i am writing this method  in the domain service inherited from LinqToEntitiesDomainService class.I am really stuck at this point.

All answers will be appreciated.

Comment: while i was searching for the answer i stumbled  onto something  here.<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155230/silverlight-database-connecting-issue> and in datacontext class  i was trying to connect the database directly so i guess i was doing something i should not do in silverlight.  so ground zero how can i get column names of a table from database using wcf ria services in silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in support for this. However, you can use the following SQL to get the columns from a table. In this example, there is a table named `Foo.Bar` where `Foo` is the schema.

```
SELECT c.name
FROM sys.objects o
JOIN sys.columns c
    ON o.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s
    ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE
    s.name = 'Foo'
    AND o.name = 'Bar'
```

I am using an Entity Framework `DbContext` to get the results.

```
var commandText = "<SQL from above>";
var contextAdapter = (IObjectContextAdapter) this;
IEnumerable<string> columnNames = contextAdapter.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>(commandText);
```

You can then add an invoke method to your DomainService.

```
[Invoke] // Use invoke for non-entities
public string[] GetColumnNames(string table)
{
    // Format the SQL and get the results;
    return columnNames.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: i tried that .bu t i get the exception  **"EntitiyCommandExecutionException"** "The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive types."